# Como puedo agregar datos de una tabla a unos inputs en la misma pagina?

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera saber se podría hacer esta función (tengo que hacerlo en la misma pagina ya que es un trabajo y no se como hacer esa parte) aquí les dejo mi código espero me puedan ayudar

```
<?php 
    include "conexion.php";

    $sql = "SELECT Id_alumno, Nombre, Curso, Jornada
            from alumnos";
    $resul = $cone->query($sql);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1  >
        <thead>
            <tr id='titulo'>
               <th>Codigo</th>
               <th>Alumno</th>
               <th>Curso</th>
               <th>Jornada</th>
               <th>Comando</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = $resul->fetch_assoc()) 
            {?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Id_alumno']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Nombre']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Curso']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Jornada']; ?></td>
                    <td>Agregar</td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <form>
        <center>
            <h1>Cuerpo</h1>
               <label>Codigo</label>
               <input type="text" name="codigo"><br><br>
               <label>Nombre del Alumno</label>
               <input type="text" name="nom"><br><br>
               <label>Grado</label>
               <input type="text" name="grad"><br><br>
               <label>Jornada</label>
               <input type="text" name="jor"><br><br>
        </center>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Se que para ustedes esto es súper sencillo

Comment: Pero no se entiende qué es lo que quieres hacer realmente. Consultas a la base de datos y parece que muestras el resultado en una tabla, luego hay un formulario... Pero no explicas si quieres llenar los input del formulario con alguna información de la que estás trayendo en la consulta. ¿? No dices si la consulta funciona, etc.

Comment: Ok, todo funciona lo que quiero yo es hacer un tipo **botón agregar** en la columna comando que al presionarlo mande los datos de esa fila a los input ya que son datos que se guardaría en otra tabla solo que el único dato realmente que guardaría seria el **Id_alumno**

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que lo que quieres conseguir es mostrar los datos que aparecen en la tabla en el interior del los inputs.

Para ello debes usar la propiedad `value` de los inputs.

Si tu intención es mostrar un formulario para cada usuario de la BD, dicho formulario debe de estar en el interior de bucle while y establecer el value a `inputs` seria muy sencillo...

```
<input type="text" name="nom" <?php echo "value='".$row['Nombre']."'"; ?> />
```

En el caso que muestras arriba... hay un único formulario creado en el exterior del bucle while... por lo que si tienes varios datos en la BD y quieres agregar a los inputs dichos datos... solo te servirá el ultimo dato de la BD.

Comment: pero en la tabla se puede agregar algún tipo de enlace para mandar los datos de la fila que escoja a los inputs?